# Expo - AuthSession.startAsync suddenly stopped redirecting back to app after it has token

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have an expo react native app which is using Expo AuthSession.startAsync to log in using an external provider.

All of a sudden this has stopped redirecting back to the app after it gets the access token and I don't know why, as far as i'm aware nothing has changed in over a year so i'm totally confused at what has happened.

This is the code... is basically does not ever return a result, it just redirects to the page with the #access_token in the query string on the modal, but nothing happens after that?

```
   const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
        authUrl: url
    });

    if (result.type === "cancel") {
        // do nothing
    } else if (result.type !== "success") {
        Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error logging in to the external provider, please try again.");
    } else {
        const accessToken = result.params.access_token;
        console.log(accessToken);
        this.props.setAccountJwt(accessToken);
        navigate("Levels");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, nothing to do with the code.

My redirect page on my website had only a script tag in and that's it.

Mobile browsers must have had an update to not run pages with only a script file in is my only guess..

As soon as I put a full html page in there with my script block to redirect in there it then sprank back to life.

```
window.location.replace('https://auth.expo.io/@@myapp' + window.location.hash);
```